# Extra spaces in the representation of numpy arrays of floats

Tags: python, numpy

Do you know why the representation of numpy array of integers has no padding:

```
>>> print array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

while the numpy array of floats has one extra space before each of the entries?

```
>>> print array([[1., 2], [3, 4]])
[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
```

(at least in Python 2.7)

I am more interested in the reason/idea behind it, less in the specific implementation details that cause it.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked `blame` to find out why authors implement as this.

Take a look at the line 584 of https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blame/master/numpy/core/arrayprint.py

```
self.max_str_len = len(str(int(max_val))) + precision + 2
```

**Because of the magic number `2`, the space is added to in front of `float` values.**

Around the line 593, `format` is determined as

```
if self.sign:
    format = '%#+'
else:
    format = '%#'
format = format + '%d.%df' % (self.max_str_len, precision)
```

As your example, `max_val` is `4.0`, and `precision` is `0`.
So `self.max_str_len` will be `3`, then `format` will be `%#3.0f`

Finally, the value printed is

```
print '%#3.0f' % 4.
# 4.
```

Comment: Can you explain why someone put a 2 there. Seems like a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Try out below:
numpy.set_printoptions(sign=' ')

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array(['dev', 'roy', 'kinder'], dtype=np.str)
print("Original Array:")
print(x)
p = np.char.join(" ", x)
print(p)
```

Comment: How would this help the OP? The OP wants to know why the extra space is there in the first place; they're not after a way to get rid of it.